# ¿Duplicar objetos similares para que contengan datos diferentes.?

Tags: java, spring-boot

### Contexto

Tengo una estructura un poco compleja de clases que asemejan un árbol de esta manera.

- Cotización

  - Procesos

    - Actividades

      - Máquinas

        - Gastos

De manera que yo puedo tener algo asi:

```
Cotizacion1
    Proceso1
        RelacionProcesoActividad1(Actividad1)
             RelacionActividadMaquina1(Maquina1) - segundos int
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1 (Gasto1)
             RelacionActividadMaquina2
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto2
         RelacionProcesoActividad2
             RelacionActividadMaquina2
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto2
     Proceso2
        RelacionProcesoActividad1
             RelacionActividadMaquina1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
             RelacionActividadMaquina2
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto2
     Proceso3
        RelacionProcesoActividad1
             RelacionActividadMaquina1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
             RelacionActividadMaquina2
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto2
         RelacionProcesoActividad2
             RelacionActividadMaquina2
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto1
                 RelacionMaquinaGasto2
```

El objeto `RelacionMaquinaGasto1` por obvias razones tiene exactamente los mismos datos en todas las partes con excepción de los segundos y un id de una clase con la que está relacionada. Esa clase con la que está relacionada me permite almacenar los datos de manera independiente (en relación a los segundos y máquinas) y esta es su estructura:

**`RelacionCotizacionMacro`**

- `id (int)` Este es el id que almacenamos en `RelacionMaquinaGasto1`
- `Cotizacion`
- `Proceso`
- `Actividad`
- `Maquina`
- `segundos (int)` Estos son los segundos que almacenamos.

Esta clase se guarda directamente en al base de datos con esta misma estructura, la diferencia es que las clases se sustituyen por los id que existen.

### ¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer?

- Creo mi estructura como al principio y puede guardarla y consultarla.
- Puedo acceder a los datos que se repiten.
- Puedo guardar los segundos en la tabla `RelacionCotizacionMacro`
- Puedo guardar esta información en la base de datos con este código sin ningún problema:

  ```
              //CONVERTIMOS EL MANEJO DE PROCESOS A MAQUINAS.
              for (Proceso proceso : manejoDeProcesos.getProcesos()) {
                  for (RelacionProcesoActividad relacionProcesoActividad
                          : proceso.getRelacionProcesoActividad()) {
                      for (RelacionActividadMaquinaModelo relacionActividadMaquinaModelo
                              : relacionProcesoActividad.getActividad().getRelacionActividadMaquinaModelo()) {

                          cotizacion.addrelacionCotizacionMacro()
                                  .setProceso(proceso)
                                  .setCotizacion(cotizacion)
                                  .setActividad(relacionProcesoActividad.getActividad())
                                  .setMaquinaModelo(relacionActividadMaquinaModelo.getMaquinaModelo())
                                  .setSegundos(relacionActividadMaquinaModelo.getSegundos());
                      }
                   }
                }
  ```

Una vez que guarde los datos en `RelacionCotizacionMacro` trato de modificarlos. Para esto tengo que seguir este procedimiento.

1. Consultar todos los datos que guarde en `RelacionCotizacionMacro` y que coincidan con la cotización que quiero modificar.  Obtengo un `arrayList`como resultado de tipo `RelacionCotizacionMacro`.
2. Filtro los procesos duplicados y obtengo un nuevo arraylist de tipo `Proceso` sin duplicados. **Automáticamente se generó la estructura que tiene el árbol que describo al principio** porque spring consulto los procesos ya existentes y con ello se trajo todas las relaciones que ya había definido. (Las actividades que están relacionadas con el proceso, las máquinas relacionadas a las actividades y por último los gastos asociados a las máquinas. Todo esto dentro de sus relaciones)

### El problema

Cuando yo guardo los datos lo hago desde el html y spring entiende que son datos diferentes(Esto no se por que lo hace así), pero si yo trato de recorrer el árbol desde java y asignar datos(los segundos a la relación de la máquina) estos se sobre escriben porque estoy modificando la misma instancia.

Esto es lo que he intentado.

```
 for (RelacionCotizacionMacro rcm : manejoDeProcesos.getCotizacion().getRelacionCotizacionMacro()) {
            for (Proceso proceso : procesosNew) {
                for (RelacionProcesoActividad rpa : proceso.getRelacionProcesoActividad()) {
                    for (RelacionActividadMaquinaModelo ramm : rpa.getActividad().getRelacionActividadMaquinaModelo()) {


                        boolean x = rcm.getProceso().getId() == proceso.getId();
                        boolean y = rcm.getActividad().getId() == rpa.getActividad().getId();
                        boolean z = rcm.getMaquinaModelo().getId() == ramm.getMaquinaModelo().getId();
                        boolean a = !ramm.isAsignado();

                        if (x && y && z && a) {
                            //Ponemos el flag asignado a la máquina puesto
                            //que puede haber muchas máquinas iguales. 
                            ramm.setAsignado(true);
                            //Copiamos los segundos. 
                            ramm.setSegundos(rcm.getSegundos());
                            //Este dato lo ocupo copiar para despues actualizar en la BD
                            ramm.setIdRelacionCotizacionMacro(rcm.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Intente crear nuevos objetos de esta manera:

```
//CREAMOS LA NUEVA LISTA DE PROCESOS QUE CONTENDRA MANEJO DE PROCESOS
        List<Proceso> procesosNew = new ArrayList<>();

        //CARGAMOS TODOS LOS PROCESOS QUE SE GUARDARON EN LA COTIZACIÓN Y LOS 
        // FILTRAMOS PARA QUITAR LOS REPETIDOS. 
        List<Proceso> procesosParaCargar = manejoDeProcesos.getCotizacion().getRelacionCotizacionMacro()
                .stream()
                //AGRUPAMOS POR PROCESOS.
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getProceso() ))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                .map(e -> e.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //ITINERAMOS SOBRE LOS PROCESOS QUE NO ESTAN REPETIDOS PARA COPIARLOS.

        procesosParaCargar.forEach(p->{
            //CREAMOS UNA NUEVA INSTANCIA DE PROCESO Y LA COPIAMOS. 
            Proceso procesoNew = new Proceso();

            //COPIAMOS TODOS LOS DATOS DEL PROCESO. 
            procesoNew
                    .setChecked(p.isChecked())
                    .setCostoTotalDeProceso(p.getCostoTotalDeProceso())
                    .setDepartamento(p.getDepartamento())
                    .setDescripcion(p.getDescripcion())
                    .setId(p.getId())
                    .setMateriaPrima(p.isMateriaPrima())
                    .setNombre(p.getNombre());

            procesosNew.add(p);

            //COPIAMOS LAS RELACIONES
            p.getRelacionProcesoActividad().forEach(rpa->{

                Actividad actividadRPA = rpa.getActividad();

                //CREAMOS UNA NUEVA ACTIVIDAD Y LA COPIAMOS
                Actividad actividadNew = new Actividad();
                actividadNew
                        .setDescripcion(actividadRPA.getDescripcion())
                        .setId(actividadRPA.getId())
                        .setNombre(actividadRPA.getNombre())
                        .setTotalGastos(actividadRPA.getTotalGastos());


                //AGREGAMOS LOS GASTOS
                actividadRPA.getRelacionActividadGasto().forEach(relGasto->{
                    //CREAMOS LA NUEVA COPIA DE GASTO
                    Gasto gastoRelGasto = relGasto.getGasto();

                    Gasto gastoNew = 
                            new Gasto()
                            .setCostoPorUnidad(gastoRelGasto.getCostoPorUnidad())
                            .setId(gastoRelGasto.getId())
                            .setNombreGasto(gastoRelGasto.getNombreGasto())
                            .setSegundos(gastoRelGasto.getSegundos())
                            .setUnidad(gastoRelGasto.getUnidad())
                            ;


                    //CREAMOS UNA NUEVA RELACION DE GASTO
                    RelacionActividadGasto relGastoNew = 
                            new RelacionActividadGasto()
                            .setActividad(actividadNew)
                            .setAsignado(relGasto.isAsignado())
                            .setGasto(gastoNew)
                            .setId(relGasto.getId())
                            .setIdRelacionCotizacionMacroGasto(relGasto.getIdRelacionCotizacionMacroGasto())
                            .setOrdenDeOperacion(relGasto.getOrdenDeOperacion())
                            .setSegundos(relGasto.getSegundos())
                            .setTotalGasto(relGasto.getTotalGasto())
                            ;
                    //ASIGANMOS LA NUEVA RELACION A LOS GASTOS DE LA ACTIVIDAD
                    actividadNew.getRelacionActividadGasto().add(relGastoNew);
                });

                //AGREGAMOS LAS MÁQUINAS.
                actividadRPA.getRelacionActividadMaquinaModelo().forEach(relMaquina->{
                    //OBTENEMOS LA MAQUINA DE LA RELACION
                    MaquinaModelo maquinaModeloRel = relMaquina.getMaquinaModelo();


                    //CREAMOS LA NUEVA MÁQUINA
                    MaquinaModelo maquinaModeloNew = 
                            new MaquinaModelo()
                            .setAnio(maquinaModeloRel.getAnio())
                            .setCosto(maquinaModeloRel.getCosto())
                            .setCostoDepreciacionSegundo(maquinaModeloRel.getCostoDepreciacionSegundo())
                            .setCostoDepreciacionTotal(maquinaModeloRel.getCostoDepreciacionTotal())
                            .setDepreciacion(maquinaModeloRel.getDepreciacion())
                            .setId(maquinaModeloRel.getId())
                            .setModelo(maquinaModeloRel.getModelo());

                    //AGREGAMOS LOS GASTOS DE LA MAQUINA 

                    maquinaModeloRel.getRelacionMaquinaModeloGasto().forEach(relGasto->{

                        //OBTENEMOS EL GASTO DE LA RELACIÓN
                        Gasto gastoRel = relGasto.getGasto();

                        //CREAMOS EL NUEVO GASTO
                        Gasto gastoNew = 
                                new Gasto()
                                .setCostoPorUnidad(gastoRel.getCostoPorUnidad())
                                .setId(gastoRel.getId())
                                .setNombreGasto(gastoRel.getNombreGasto())
                                .setSegundos(gastoRel.getSegundos())
                                .setUnidad(gastoRel.getUnidad());

                        //CREAMOS LA RELACION
                        RelacionMaquinaModeloGasto relGastoNew = 
                                new RelacionMaquinaModeloGasto()
                                .setConsumoHora(relGasto.getConsumoHora())
                                .setCostoPorSegundo(relGasto.getCostoPorSegundo())
                                .setCostoTotal(relGasto.getCostoTotal())
                                .setGasto(gastoNew)
                                .setId(relGasto.getId())
                                .setMaquinaModelo(maquinaModeloNew);

                        maquinaModeloNew.getRelacionMaquinaModeloGasto().add(relGastoNew);
                    });


                    //CREAMOS LA NUEVA RELACION
                    RelacionActividadMaquinaModelo relMaquinaNew = 
                            new RelacionActividadMaquinaModelo()
                            .setActividad(actividadNew)
                            .setAsignado(relMaquina.isAsignado())
                            .setCostoTotalMaquina(relMaquina.getCostoTotalMaquina())
                            .setId(relMaquina.getId())
                            .setIdRelacionCotizacionMacro(relMaquina.getIdRelacionCotizacionMacro())
                            .setMaquinaModelo(maquinaModeloNew)
                            .setOrdenDeOperacion(relMaquina.getOrdenDeOperacion())
                            .setSegundos(relMaquina.getSegundos());

                    actividadNew.getRelacionActividadMaquinaModelo().add(relMaquinaNew);

                });

                //CREAMOS UNA NUEVA RELACIÓN Y LA COPIAMOS.                 
                RelacionProcesoActividad relProAct = new RelacionProcesoActividad();
                relProAct
                        .setActividad(actividadRPA)
                        .setAsignada(rpa.isAsignada())
                        .setCostoTotalDeActividad(rpa.getCostoTotalDeActividad())
                        .setId(rpa.getId())
                        .setOrdenDeProceso(rpa.getOrdenDeProceso())
                        .setProceso(p)
                        .setTotalGastos(rpa.getTotalGastos());

                procesoNew.getRelacionProcesoActividad().add(relProAct);
            });
        });
```

Pero no obtengo buenos resultados. Cuando los objetos están repetidos me ignora el flag de la máquina.

### ¿Qué es lo que no puedo hacer?

Cargar los segundos de la máquina guardados en `RelacionCotizacionMacro`  itinerando sobre  `List<Proceso>` para encontrar las coincidencias y mostrarlos en el html con su correspondiente par.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entendí.

Tu necesitas, que el objeto RelacionMaquinaGasto1 tenga el mismo Id(PK) para relacionarlo en la DB con los objetos padres... PERO el objeto cambia su idPadree y número de segundos... sin embargo spring a la hora de hacer el mapeo te identifica cada objeto RelacionMaquinaGasto1(hijo) como uno diferente en cada objeto padre (es decir no es el mismo ya que cambia su PK).

Eso entiendo yo.

Lo que yo veo, es que estas tratando de hacer una relación muchos a muchos (Muchos RelacionProcesoActividad pueden tener muchos RelacionMaquinaGasto1 y viceversa)

Lo más lógico sería normalizar es decir, crear una ideantidad llamada RelacionProcesoActividadRelacionMaquinaGasto1 que tenga lo siguiente:

Un id único, y un objeto de tipo RelacionProcesoActividad, un objeto de tipo RelacionMaquinaGasto1 y el tiempo en segundos en el que difiere

Es decir, elimina los segundos del objeto RelacionMaquinaGasto1 y añadelos en el objeto nuevo RelacionProcesoActividadRelacionMaquinaGasto1, de esta manera la estructura del objeto RelacionMaquinaGasto1 no cambia y spring no generará nuevos objetos tratando de satisfacer las necesidades de la inyección de dependencias.

Comment: Ya tengo una relacion como la que especificas donde guardo todos los datos que me hacen llegar a los segundos de la Máquina. El problema esta cuando los trato de modificar. Leo de la tabla donde están guardados los segundos y al tratar de cargarlo en las clases para mostrarlo estas se sobre escriben por que son el mismo objeto. Si tengo dos `Relación1` para spring son lo mismo y si modifico algo en una la otra tambien se modifica (Son el mismo objeto)